# Can a terrestial planet have a core of metallic hydrogen?

Tags: science-based, planets, astronomy

Let's say somehow, a yellow dwarf like our sun was sent hurtling through space, and smacked into a red giant with enough force to cause the two to go supernova.

With the release of large amounts of metals and gases, large amounts of hydrogen started grouping together and forming a core, this core attracts large amounts of materials from its surroundings including the metals.

Is it possible that if enough of the solid elements(like iron, nickel, etc.) exist and the hydrogen core is massive enough to attract them with gravity, they could provide enough mass to force the hydrogen core to undergo a phase change? Or due to the different densities, the positions would simply reverse themselves as hydrogen is shunted out of the core?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't happen for two reasons.

First Metallic hydrogen is a phase change that only occurs at levels of pressure that far exceed Earths core, or anything you'd call terrestrial.

Second, terrestrial planets always start out molten. Even if the hydrogen were somehow able to keep metallic form until it was encased in rock, hydrogen is less dense than silicon, iron, nickel, etc. The heavier elements would push their way into the metallic hydrogen, fragmenting the core and lifting it to the outside world where it would turn to gas.